# Chess AI implementation in Java project

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax

I'm currently implementing a chess AI into my chess game. Now I'm currently struggling how to handle the game state to the AI.

Because I feel like the AI, needs the up to date properties from a board, or game class (in my case, I send a game class). But I'm wondering, that this is the wrong way. Why?

Whenever I'm calculating the move for the AI using minmax, I'm trying to place movements on the board, but the problem is this should not be on the board. Because the second player is basically using the board. I feel like it will crash, because whenever the AI *tries* a movement, it will try to get updated on the board which results in a crash.

So I think I have to create a fake/mock copy (with the properties that are needed, list of available moves, piece color, player, etc.) of the game/board and send that to the AI. But what would be the best way to do this?

My current code setup of the minimax algorithm
relevance other codes that are used: https://hastebin.com/niqaderule.java:

```
public class MiniMax implements MoveStrategy {

    private final BoardEvaluator boardEvaluator;
    private int searchDepth;


    public MiniMax(BoardEvaluator boardEvaluator, int searchDepth) {
        this.boardEvaluator = boardEvaluator;
        this.searchDepth = searchDepth;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MiniMax{" +
                "boardEvaluator=" + boardEvaluator +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public Move execute(ChessGame game) {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Move calculatedBestMove = null;

        int highestSeenValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int lowestSeenValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int currentValue;

        System.out.println("computer thinks" + " depth= " + this.searchDepth);

        var numberOfAllMoves = game.getBoard().getAllAvailableMoves(PieceColor.BLACK);

        for(Move move : game.getBoard().getAllAvailableMoves(PieceColor.BLACK)){
             game.getBoard().movePiece(move.getSelectedPiece(), move);
             currentValue = calculateValue(game);
             if(game.getCurrentTurn() == game.getPlayers().get(0) && currentValue >= highestSeenValue)
             {
                 highestSeenValue = currentValue;
                 calculatedBestMove = move;
             }
             else if(game.getCurrentTurn() == game.getPlayers().get(1) && currentValue <= lowestSeenValue){
                 lowestSeenValue = currentValue;
                 calculatedBestMove = move;
             }

        }
        long CalculationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        return  calculatedBestMove;
    }

    public int calculateValue(ChessGame game){
        if(game.getCurrentTurn() == game.getPlayers().get(0)){
           return  min(game, -1);
        }
            return max(game,  -1);
    }


    public int min(ChessGame game, int depth){

        if(depth == 0 || game.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.BLACK_CHECK_MATE || game.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.WHITE_CHECK_MATE){
            return this.boardEvaluator.evaluate(game, depth);
        }

        int lowestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(Move move: game.getBoard().getAllAvailableMoves(PieceColor.BLACK)){
            game.getBoard().movePiece(move.getSelectedPiece(), move);
            int currentValue = max(game, depth -1);
            if(currentValue <= lowestValue)
            {
                lowestValue = currentValue;
            }
        }
        return lowestValue;
    }

    public int max(ChessGame game, int depth){
        if(depth == 0 || game.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.BLACK_CHECK_MATE || game.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.WHITE_CHECK_MATE){
            return this.boardEvaluator.evaluate(game, depth);
        }

        int highestSeenValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for(Move move: game.getBoard().getAllAvailableMoves(PieceColor.BLACK)){
            game.getBoard().movePiece(move.getSelectedPiece(), move);

            int currentValue = min(game, depth -1);
            if(currentValue <= highestSeenValue)
            {
                highestSeenValue = currentValue;
            }
        }
        return highestSeenValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Board representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_representation_(computer_chess)). You need evaluation function that tells you the score of the current position and a set of available moves.

Comment: Just to be clear, every time you get a set of moves you pass a copy of the board with the new state. It should be a recursive function call that exits once you reach the desired depth. Scoring function is up to you.

Comment: As an alternative to copying the board, you could design a `takeBack` method that will undo a move, bringing the state back *exactly* to what it was before the move (including state concerning castling, en-passent capture, promotion, ...). This may turn out to be a cheaper operation than copying the state.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 common ways of doing this:

1. Create a deep copy of the board representation before making the move (before the recursive call), and then send the board copy to the minimax function.
2. Make the move on the board, send it to the minimax function, and then take back the move to get the original board state back.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I started doing similar project with various AI bots, the approach I took was to use SerializationUtils from Apache commons-lang3. Make sure you board state class implements Serializable interface and then you can do some like this:

`final Board state = SerializationUtils.clone(currentState)`

You find more info here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html